# UItableView selection issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a tableview with the name HomeTable. I set delegates and datasource but **didselectrowatindexpath** method is not calling.below is my code.i created hometablecell which is also correct but I didn't know what is the mistake I have done.please help me out.thank you

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
    }

    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        if ([HomeTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [HomeTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([HomeTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [HomeTable setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        if (RestName.count==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return RestName.count;
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

        HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSDictionary *ResDiction = [RestName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.ResLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Bask size:16];
        cell.LabelRes.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Bask size:16];
        cell.ResLabel.text = [ResDiction objectForKey:@"business_name"];
        cell.LabelRes.text= [ResDiction objectForKey:@"business_category"];
        cell.ResLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        cell.LabelRes.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

        return cell;

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (indexPath.row==0) {

            UIStoryboard *Story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            Beverages *sachin=[Story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Bever"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sachin animated:YES];
        }else{

            UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Selected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is the didselectrowatindexpath ? in your i could not find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code what it should look like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
    }

    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        if ([HomeTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [HomeTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([HomeTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [HomeTable setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        if (RestName.count==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return RestName.count;
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

        HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSDictionary *ResDiction = [RestName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.ResLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Bask size:16];
        cell.LabelRes.font=[UIFont fontWithName:Bask size:16];
        cell.ResLabel.text = [ResDiction objectForKey:@"business_name"];
        cell.LabelRes.text= [ResDiction objectForKey:@"business_category"];
        cell.ResLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        cell.LabelRes.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

        return cell;

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (indexPath.row==0) {

            UIStoryboard *Story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            Beverages *sachin=[Story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Bever"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sachin animated:YES];
        }else{

            UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Selected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }
```

Also please make sure the from UITableview(if its from XIB file) cell selection is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Ans is your method is wrong

You need to use `didselectrowatindexpath` Method

instead of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` Method.

Answer (score 1):

You implemented the wrong method: you implemented did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath.

The correct method is [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row==0) {

        UIStoryboard *Story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        Beverages *sachin=[Story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Bever"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sachin animated:YES];
    }else{

        UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Selected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```